# Google Map API's reverse geocoding

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am looking at the reverse geocoding for one of my applications. Is it possible to determine, the address or geocode of an address by giving an input ( geocode, diatnce from geocode and line of sight ( angle ) ). Does any of the Map APIs have these capability? Apologies if the question is very generic.

Thanks,
Srini.

Answer (score 0):

For geocoding Read this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en

and use this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

For distance Read this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=en

and use this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

Comment: Hi Dinu,   Thanks for your comment. I have already read this. But my question how do i find an address by passing not just latlng but also angle and distance from a particular latlng.

Comment: due to the earth's slightly ellipsoid shape , i think this is imposible.Distance between degrees varies.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that we can do it with math.

Use link http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html